# CIDR allocation to 8 subnets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, subnet, private-subnet

I have my VPC configured with `10.0.0.0/16` CIDR. I want to create around 7-10 subnets in this VPC.

On my calculation, I have decided to have 8 subnets where each subnet can host 8192 resources (`8192*8=65536`).

As per my calculation, `2^13=8192`. Subtracting it from the max size of 32 `(32-13)= 19`. So is it `10.0.0.0/19`? If that is so, this would be the CIDR for first subnet. What would be for the rest 7?

I have tried with `10.0.0.0/19`. Next when I go with `10.0.1.0/19`, it is throwing an error.

But I am in confused state as in how can I allocate ipv4 CIDR to 8 subnets? What would be starting and ending range? How can I calculate what IPV4 CIDR can I allocate to each subnet?

Answer (score 0):

**Tip:** Always use a [CIDR calculator](https://www.google.com/search?q=cidr+calculator) when determining CIDR ranges. Unassisted, it is too hard for the human brain!

The subnets for `/19` ranges would be:

- `10.0.0.0/19`
- `10.0.32.0/19`
- `10.0.64.0/19`
- `10.0.96.0/19`
- `10.0.128.0/19`
- `10.0.160.0/19`
- `10.0.192.0/19`
- `10.0.224.0/19`

Each of these ranges contain 8192 IP addresses. The portion before the slash identifies the *first* IP address in the range.

You were receiving an error because `10.0.1.0` is *within* the `10.0.0.0/19` range, and does not start that range.

Many people like using `/24` because it simply changes the second-last number, eg: `10.0.0.0/24`, `10.0.1.0/24`, `10.0.2.0/24`. However, each of these ranges only contain 256 IP addresses.

Comment: Can you let me know how did you choose 0,32,64 etc? Is there any calculation?

Comment: Go to a CIDR calculator, enter `10.0.0.0/19`. It will tell you that it goes from `10.0.0.0` to `10.0.31.255`. Therefore, the next range starts with `10.0.32.0`. It matches your calculations because `32*256=8192`, so each `/19` range would increment by `32` in the third dotted number.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar problem in the past, so I built a tool to automate the calculation. You can check it out at: https://houqp.github.io/vpcstudio/.

If you provide it with 10.0.0.0/16 as the CIDR and layout the number of subnets you want in the yaml, it should automatically generate the optimal CIDR range for each subnet for you.